# Create Polymer menu like Google IO 2015 website

Tags: polymer, googleio, polymer-designer-tool

I am new to polymer. 
I want to build menu like Google IO 15 website. [image]

I tried by adding core-toolbar to core-scroll-header-panel.

```
<core-scroll-header-panel headermargin="128" condenses headerheight="192" id="core_scroll_header_panel">
  <core-toolbar id="core_toolbar" class="tall">
    <core-icon-button icon="arrow-back" id="core_icon_button"></core-icon-button>
    <div id="div" flex>
      <core-item id="core_item2" icon="home" label="Home" horizontal center layout></core-item>
      <core-item id="core_item" icon="account-box" label="Our Objectives" horizontal center layout></core-item>
    </div>
    <div id="div1" class="bottom indent">Title</div>
    <core-item id="core_item1" icon="settings" label="Business Activities" horizontal center layout></core-item>
  </core-toolbar>
  <section id="section" content></section>
</core-scroll-header-panel>
```

But that went like below shown image

[image]

How can I get that ripple effect or hover effects like in [Google IO 2015](https://events.google.com/io2015/) website.

Is there any other way to achieve it.

Comment: The menu is the element `paper-tabs`

Answer (score 1):

Just add paper-tabs to core-scroll-header-panel and it worked.

Below is the code snippet

```
    <core-scroll-header-panel id="core_scroll_header_panel">
       <core-toolbar id="core_toolbar" class="tall">
         <div id="div" flex>
         <paper-tabs selected="1" selectedindex="1" horizontal center layout>
          <paper-tab id="paper_tab" flex horizontal layout>Home</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab id="paper_tab1" flex horizontal layout active>Phone</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab id="paper_tab2" flex horizontal layout>Activities</paper-tab>
      </paper-tabs>
    </div>
  </core-toolbar>
  <section id="section" content></section>
</core-scroll-header-panel>
```

I got ripple effect too as they are paper elements.